# Counts of various elements in various files

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk, grep

So I have about 1000 files that are multiple columns, but I'm only interested in some stats of two of those columns. If $4 was something like a star's spectral class (ie a unique value) and $5 in each of these files was a result, like seen, unseen, unknown, etc, is there a recommended way to grep or awk out the stats like so across the 1000 or so files so I get something like:

```
Type O, #verified, #not-verified, #property-j, ...
Type B, ...
Type A, ...
.
.
.
Type i,
```

Where, in each file, you'd see something like:

```
$1, $2, $3, Spectral Type, Result
foo, foo, foo, A, verified
foo, foo, foo, G, verified
foo, foo, foo, A, unknown
foo, foo, foo, F, verified
foo, foo, foo, G, verified
foo, foo, foo, K, verified
foo, foo, foo, K, seen
```

Comment: we need a better example of your required output to make any meaningful comments or suggestions. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is: "How do I generate output of the form "Type $4, $5" where $4 and $5 are the 4th and 5th columns of the input, respectively?" one solution is:

```
for i in list of input file; do
  awk '{print "Type "$4, $5}' $i > $i.result
done
```

This gives the output that it seems you want, but relies on the all columns not containing whitespace.  If there may be whitespace, you can do:

```
 awk '{printf( "Type %s, %s", $4, $5 )}' FS=, $i > $i.result
```

but you may want to trim the extra whitespace that this will generate.  Please note that although in the example I have hardcoded the list of input files to be the 4 files names "list", "of", "input", and "file", I do not expect you to type the names in.  Instead, you should generate them in some fashion, and I'm merely demonstrated one (of many!) methods of iterating over a set of files.  It seems that the heart of this question is the portion dealing with `awk`, and not the iteration.

A second reading of the question indicates that you have exactly one row per input file and you want to summarize the results in a single file.  In that case, just do:

```
cat list of all files | awk '{print "Type "$4, $5}'
```

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say the second part of the question was tabulating the stats of the various types in the resultant file, not just reading off what they were. Using awk to pull out the columns I want to analyze works well, but if I were to then take those 2 columns I extracted and want to see the counts of verified, unknown, seen, etc, then what should I do?

Comment: You should add them up and output the sums!

Answer (score 1):

If the separator is just comma, and doesn't need CSV parsing with escaping, use the cut utility:

```
cat $file | cut -d, -f4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -aF, -nle '{${$h{@F[3]}}{@F[4]}=1}END{while(($k,$v)=each%h){print"$k, @{[keys%$v]}";}}' files
```

EDIT

Why this solves the problem.

For flags info type

```
perl --help
```

The algorithm

```
{..} END{..}    # first block is evaluated on each line, END block only once at the end
```

@F[3] should have been written $F[3], the difference is that @F[3] is an array of one element and $F[3] is the element

```
${h{$F[3]}}     # gets value or creates and return a new entry in the hash %h with key $F[3] third element of array @F
${..}{$F[4]}=1  # supposes that value in hash %h is type HASHREF and creates a new entry with key
```

entire expression could be written (maybe easier), but it was the first syntax which came to me first

```
$h{$F[3]}{$F[4]}=1
```

END

```
while(($k,$v)=each%h)  # loop over entries of hash %h
"@{[..]}"   # is a trick to display array in a double quote expression
%$v         # dereferences HASHREF
```

A closer solution of the problem:

```
perl -lnaF'/\s*,\s*/' -e '{$h{$F[3]}{$F[4]}=1;}END{while(($k,$v)=each%h){print("Type $k, ",join(", ",map("#$_",keys%$v)));}}'
```

Note: parentheses after print are optional in this case but kept for more readability, semi-colons too before closing curly braket